# What happens when you terminate a UK Ph.D. in the second year?

Tags: phd, masters, united-kingdom

I've read that after you "pass" the first year of your Ph.D.program you can either continue normally or stop and get a masters degree.

What procedure should one follow in the latter case? Do you get any official document (diploma, certificate) and if so, does this document have any value?

Comment: It's often not in the first year, but whenever it is, the procedure will depend on your university's rules. The master's degree you get is real master's degree. You should get a diploma.

Comment: Should there be a thesis written additionally or is it based on the work you have done till the termination moment (1st year report)?

Comment: You can get a master's at many universities on coursework alone, but it takes more than a year. We don't even know what country you're in, and the policies vary quite a lot.

Comment: Let's say a Research based Ph.D. in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK, typically students are not "officially" PhD students until after they successfully complete their first year report. I say "officially" because from  a student perspective you are a PhD student from day one, but students who do not progress at the end of the first year, either because they drop out or fail, do not count against completion rates. This means from a book keeping vantage the student is not a PhD student. Typically students are awarded an MPhil after successfully completing the first year report. You would definitely receive a diploma and there may be a graduation ceremony.

You should talk to your director of post grad studies to figure out the exact procedure. The timing can be critical in making sure you do not count against completion rates.

As for the value of an MPhil, that is a difficult question. It might have some value in industry since there is a big difference between failing out and dropping out, but a year of post graduate research experience is not all that valuable to industry. The more important value may be personal in at it says that you left on your own terms and did not fail out.

Answer (score 2):

The situation here varies wildly depending on your particular program, which is strongly determined by your particular university, which in turn is strongly influenced by country.  Some places will allow it after two years; others have a specific non-time-based criteria (e.g., completion of a Ph.D. proposal or being ABD); others do not allow a Masters exit at all.

In the UK, Ph.D. students are often expected to have a Masters before they even start, so you are definitely not talking about a standard case in that system and need to talk to people at your particular institution to find out the answer.